# How to remove rows based on the presence of text in another row?

Tags: r

I am trying to remove rows from a dataframe based on one field if there is any text in another field.  If column "c" contains a 0 and column "a" has any text, I would like to remove the row.  How can I remove rows based on the presence of text in another row?

Some bad psuedo-code to help clarify:

`if "a" is text AND c == 0: remove row`

---

```
# Sample Data
a = c("text1", "text2", "", "text4", "text5")
b = c(1,2,3,4,5)
c = c(63.5, 23.4, 0, 34.34, 0)

df = data.frame(a,b,c)
```

[image]

---

Intended output:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is

```
subset(df, (a=="" | c!=0) )

#       a b     c
# 1 text1 1 63.50
# 2 text2 2 23.40
# 3       3  0.00
# 4 text4 4 34.34
```

also

```
subset(df, !(a!="" & c==0))
```

both are [logically equivalent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) in the absence of missing values.

Comment: Great, Is there a quick tweak to perform the same action, but using `NA` instead of missing values `""`?

Comment: Well, you don't have NA values in your example. NA values are distinct from zero-length character values. You can test for NA with `is.na()`.